# How to scrape logos from websites?

Tags: screen-scraping, html-parsing

First off, this is not a question about how to scrape websites. I am fully aware of the tools available to me to scrape (css_parser, nokogiri, etc. I'm using Ruby to do the scraping).

This is more of an overarching question on the best possible solution to scrape the **logo** of a website starting with nothing but a website address.

The two solutions I've begun to create are these:

1. Use Google AJAX APIs to do an image search that is scoped to the site in question, with the query "logo", and grab the first result. This gets the logo, I'd say, about 30% of the time.
2. The problem with the above is that Google doesn't really seem to care about CSS image replaced logos (ie. H1 text that is image replaced with the logo). The solution I've tentatively come up with is to pull down all CSS files, scan for url() declarations, and then look for the words header or logo in the file names.

Solution two is problematic because of the many idiosyncrasies of all the people who write CSS for websites. They use Header instead of logo in the file name. Sometimes the file name is random, saying nothing about a logo. Other times, it's just the wrong image.

I realize I *might* be able to do something with some sort of machine learning, but I'm on a bit of a deadline for a client and need something fairly capable soon.

So with all that said, if anyone has any "out of the box" thinking on this one, I'd love to hear it. If I can create a solution that works well enough, I plan on open-sourcing the library for any other interested parties :)

Thanks!

Comment: Also, I'd like to add that I'm doing this to cut down on the manual image uploading process for my client. We'll be pulling in thousands of records, and I'd like them to be able to do as little manual uploading as possible. Thanks!

Comment: what about doing something like combining one of your proposed searches with: a google search limited to the root url to identify more than one page on the site. Scan two or three pages for images, and find any that are common to all of the searched pages. If there were multiple results to all pages, you'd need to develop some sort of selection criteria, perhaps on size, maybe on order within the page...but I think that would be a bit of trial and error to see what worked best. Then you could compare the results from the two approaches, and if they agree, maybe it's the logo...

Comment: That seems like a great solution! I'm fairly new to SO (long-time lurker though), but why not post that as an answer?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Ruby

Comment: Modified. Thanks for your blunt but true comment.

Comment: I'd suggest asking this question on [WebMasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) as this question has a large component of site design and page structuring to it. There might be some common practices they use that can help your heuristics be more intelligent.

Comment: Thanks Tin Man. I'll go ahead and do that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an application will definetely help you, but I believe in the end there will some manual work involved. Here's what I would do.

- Have your application store in a database a link to all images on a website that are larger than a specified dimension so that you can weed out small icons.
- Then you can setup a form to access these results. You may want to setup the database table to store the website url and relationship between the url and image links.

Even if it we're possible to write an application to truly figure out if it was a logo or not seems like it would be a massive amount of code. In the end, it would probably weed out even more than the above, but you have to take into account it could be faster for human to visually parse the results then the time it took for you to write and test the complex code.

Comment: Ooh. That's great, but I would suggest instead of downloading and storing every image (we're talking about 10,000 sites at least, and every one of those is bound to have tons of images), I instead save a url to all those images and ajax them into the admin form... Same concept, just way less to store on our servers.

Comment: This also begs to be farmed out to Mechanical Turk :D Thanks!

Comment: @Keith Hanson, Since you are talking about a huge scope of web sites why not create a database that stores a link to the found images. Each link could belong to the url of the web site in the database. Then you could open up the detail for bestbuy.com which would list links, or images for that specific website on that page.

Comment: @Nick That's pretty much exactly what I was thinking. Small modification on your original answer (don't literally **download** the image, just store the address).

Comment: @Keith Hanson, I modified my answer.

Comment: Since I think that most of the answers are going to be more or less variations on this (ie. let a human do this), I'll go ahead and flag this as the answer. Thanks @Nick!

Answer (score 19):

Check this API by Clearbit. It's super simple to use:

Just send a query to:
https://logo.clearbit.com/[enter-domain-here]

For example:
https://logo.clearbit.com/www.stackoverflow.com

and get back the logo image!

More about it [here](http://blog.clearbit.com/logo/)

Comment: Just checked. Unfortunately, this solution didn't work on 23 Feb 2023.

Comment: @KirMazur It works! what url did you try

Comment: Sorry, tried a few times your link and had 403 error all the time. Now it WORKS! Thank you!

Comment: But unfortunately doesn't have the SVG format as an option (only JPG and PNG).

Answer (score 5):

I had to find logos for ~10K websites for a previous project and tried the same technique you mentioned of extracting the image with "logo" in the URL. My variation was I loaded each webpage in webkit so that all images were loaded from CSS or JavaScript. This technique gave me logos for ~40% of websites.

Then I considered creating an app like Nick suggested to manually select the logo for the remaining websites, however I realized it was more cost effective to just give these to someone cheap (who I found via [Elance](https://www.elance.com/)) to do the work manually.

So I suggest don't bother solving this properly with a fully technical solution - outsource the manual labour.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another simple way to solve this problem is to get all leaf nodes and get the first

```
<a><img src="http://example.com/a/file.png" /></a>
```

you can lookup for projects to get html leaf nodes on the net or use regular expressions to get all html tags.

Comment: I think this is a great answer and will work for most websites.

Answer (score 0):

I used C# console app with HtmlAgilityPack nuget package to scrape logos from over 600+ sites.
Algorithm is that you get all images that have "logo" in url. 
The challenges you will face with during such extraction are:

- Relative images
- Base url is CDN HTTP/HTTPS (if you don't know
  protocol before you make a request)
- Images have ? or & with query
  string at the end

With that things in mind I got approximately 70% of success but some images were not actual logos.